# a WordPress post from the Future problem

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks, blogs

I recently installed wordpress 3.0 on Freehostia and the only thing that's giving me issues is the post date. It seems to give a post date one day in the future of when i actually posted it. While this isn't hugely troubling, it does provide a puzzle. Help??

Comment: What is the server's date set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be as simple as a time zone issue. What time does your General Settings page think it is?

[image: WordPress Time Settings]

Comment: got that but it thinks it's February and it;s not